# file like io data structure in python that does not use files at all

Tags: python, select, io, stringio

I am looking for a file like io data structure in python that does not use files at all. So just a memory file.  I tried [cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO), which is quite what I was looking for with the limitation that it is not usable via [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html). That is sound, but is there a data structure that fulfills both requirements in some way? I think select is a nice and comfortable way to check fds for updates.

Comment: The reason select doesn't work on StringIO is that select doesn't work on regular files at all. You can't use it to check if a file or file like object has been updated.

Comment: I can use select on file descriptors. Hence f = open(filename) and select.select([f],[],[]) should work, right? So I would recognise, whether something is ready to read.

Comment: @mkind `select()` reports files as always ready for I/O, which leads to a busy waiting loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although creating files on the file system, [SpooledTemporaryFiles](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes, sockets -- no content on the disk and they can be used with `select`.